# How to sort part of items in generic list

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a List object that contains items in following type

```
public class Item{

    public int Type; //this can be only 0 or 1
    public string Text;


}
```

I would like to sort the entire list by the Type first and then do another sort by Text for only items that have type is 1?

How to achieve this?

Many thanks

Ming

Comment: So, if type can only be 0 or 1, isn't this a great time to use an `enum`? `public enum MyType { TypeA = 0, TypeB = 1 };`

Comment: What have you tried?  Does it need to be done as two separate calls (so a user can select "order by: type" OR "filter by: type")?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
var ordered = list.OrderBy(i => i.Type == 0 ? "" : i.Text);
```

This is assuming there are no empty Text strings where i == 0. If you can't make that assumption, the following would work:

```
var ordered = list.OrderBy(i => i.Type).ThenBy(i => i.Type == 0 ? "" : i.Text);
```

By giving all items with a 0 Type the same value, you'll leave them all in their initial order, while sorting other items by their Text value.

On a side note, this is a code smell:

```
public int Type; //this can be only 0 or 1
```

At a glance, that sounds like it ought to be a boolean or a custom `enum` type. After taking a deeper look at what you're trying to do, it sounds like maybe you're not expecting `Text` to even be a legitimate value if Type is 0. If that's the case, you should consider using class inheritance to actually differentiate one item type from another.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't perfectly clear. It sounds like you want TWO different sorts, not a sort on one field, and then a stable re-sort when the `Type` equals `1`?

Assuming the former:

```
var sortByType = items.OrderBy(x => x.Type)
                      .ToList();
var sortTheOnesByText = items.Where(x => x.Type == 1)
                             .OrderBy(x => x.Text)
                             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Item> items;

items = items.OrderBy(i => i.Type).ThenBy(i => i.Type == 1 ? i.Text : null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement `IComparable<Item>`
See details with example [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx)
And than just use `List<T>.Sort()` method

Comment: +1 This is a worthwhile approach - Adding example code would make this answer better.  Note though, implementation can sometimes be trickier than you think: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/01/20/spot-the-defect-bad-comparisons-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind ordering Type 0 items as well then you can do

```
var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(i => i.Type).ThenBy(i => i.Text);
```

Otherwise, if you need to preserve the original order for Type 0 items, then you can do

```
var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(i => i.Type).ThenBy(i => i.Type == 0 ? "A" : i.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to put all the type=0 at the front and all the type=1 at the back, and also sort by text where type=1.

```
items.OrderBy(item => item.Type).ThenBy (item => type == 0 ? "" : item.Text)
```